# Echo final destination URL for use with 404 pages PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a 404 page that shows just the end of the URL as part of a paragraph, like;

*myurl.com/**thiswasmistyped.php***

I don't want the user to be able to see the `.php` extension, nor the rest of the URL path except the page.

Here's what I have so far.

```html
<?php
    $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // Get script filename without any path information
    $url = str_replace( array( '.php', '.htm', '.html' ), '', $page ); 
    $page ); //
    $page = str_replace( array('-', '_'), ' ', $page); 
    $page = ucwords( $page ); //
    $url = ucwords( $url );
?>

<p>We don't think you meant to come to <?php echo $url; ?>. Please try finding another page :)</p>
```

Ideally, the error page name would be upper-case so the final result would be something like;

```
We don't think you meant to come to <?php echo $url; ?> Please try finding another page :)
```

but based on *myurl.com/**thiswasmistyped.php*** it would show as:

```
We don't think you meant to come to Thiswasmistyped Please try finding another page :)
```

Without the extension. I've already configured `.htaccess` to do this. I just need the content to update based on the page URL. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the best solution would be to use routers. it saves you from calling heavy artillery

Comment: I have no idea what that means? @Saliou673, My code is almost working

Comment: try this [link](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php) you will understand

Comment: That's not relevant? I just need to be able to get the final `/page.php` and echo it as 'Page' upper-case  on the page without showing any other parts of the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need the content to update based on the page URL

If I really understand your question and based on your code you can use the $_SERVER variable to change dynamically your content.

you can use the request URI:

```
ucfirst(substr($x=substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.')),strrpos($x,'/')+1)) ;
```

or the script filename :

```
ucfirst(substr($x=substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.')),strrpos($x,'/')+1)) ;
```

or even like in your own code the PHP_SELF index which also point to the same script :

```
ucfirst(substr($x=substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.')),strrpos($x,'/')+1)) ;
```

Comment: With using `ucfirst(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],1,strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.')-1));` It still returns the full address, just not the domain. What would I use?

Comment: ok did you test the two other options too?Please var_dump it and add it in a comment

Comment: Only the last one works. That shows the path after the domain. I need to hide all of the path except for the final destination `/final.php` but also hide the `.php` extension.

Comment: That works for showing the page name. The server shows `Error` from `Error.html`, I need it to be able to display whatever the user has typed to say something like `Sorry Error doesn't exist` so if a user typed `hme` instead of `home` it'd be able to dynamically update the page saying `Sorry Hme doesn't exist`

Comment: so you can mark this question solved first and the next level is to learn how to use route and set 404 error page.Then on this page, you will be able to catch the wrong url and update your content as expected.Don't forget to mark this question as solved.

Comment: Will do. I've used `.htaccess`

Comment: Please see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829352/creating-dynamic-404-pages) I think the way I've outlined is a much more simple solution.