# Creating dynamic 404 pages

Tags: php

I have a 404 page and I'm using `php` to output the page URL. My page is saved on the server as `error.php`, The server should be able to say to the user `Sorry Error does not exist."

Currently my code shows just the name of the page capitalised and without the extension. That's fine if the user has gone to `domain.com/error.php` but if the user mistypes something like `domain.com/abutus` I'd need the server to say `Sorry Abtus does not exist.`

This is what I'm working with:

```html
<?php
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // Get script filename without any path information
$url = str_replace( array( '.php', '.htm', '.html' ), '', $page ); // Remove extensions
$page = str_replace( array( '.php', '.htm', '.html' ), '', $url); // Remove extensions
$page = str_replace( array('-', '_'), ' ', $page); // Change underscores/hyphens to spaces
$page = ucwords( $page ); // uppercase first letter of every word
$url = ucwords( $url ); // uppercase first letter of every word

?>

<p class="404">Sorry, <?php echo ucfirst(substr($x=substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.')),strrpos($x,'/')+1)) ; ?> does not exist.</p>
```

I just need to have this update based on the URL entered by the user and display that rather than the filename. It's much easier than creating and storing a new page for each possible error. I don't want to waste the server space so one dynamic page that updates would be ideal.

I've not been able to find anything relating to this so any help at all would be appreciated.

`UPDATE`

```html
<?php
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // Get script filename without any path information
$url = str_replace( array( '.php', '.htm', '.html' ), '', $page ); // Remove extensions
$page = str_replace( array( '.php', '.htm', '.html' ), '', $url); // Remove extensions
$page = str_replace( array('-', '_'), ' ', $page); // Change underscores/hyphens to spaces
$page = ucwords( $page ); // uppercase first letter of every word
$url = ucwords( $url ); // uppercase first letter of every word

?>

<p class="404">Sorry, <?php echo ucfirst(substr($x=substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.')),strrpos($x,'/')+1)) ; ?> does not exist.</p>
```

I've added the new code. If the user visits `mydomain.com/url` it doesn't echo but does with `mydomain.com/url.php`

`UPDATE 2`

```html
<?php
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>

<p>Sorry, <?php echo ucfirst(substr($x=substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.')),strrpos($x,'/')+1)) ; ?> does not exist</p>
```

I just need it to be able to give the URL that was typed even if the user hasn't provided an extension. It works with `/page.php` but if the user types `/page` it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom error page using .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Then in the code you can refer to $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] to display the requested url and tell the user that it doesn't exist with just this code :

```
<?php
$x=substr($x=substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'.')),strrpos($x,'/')+1);
if(!$x)
    $x=substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/')+1);
?>
<p class="404">Sorry, <?php echo ucfirst($x) ?> does not exist.</p>
```

Comment: Close. It works with `/page.php` but if the user types `/page` it still shows the whole filepath?

Comment: Great, thank you. Still learning. Didn't know it could be done with so little code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom error page using .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Then in the code you can refer to $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] to display the requested url and tell the user that it doesn't exist.

Comment: That works. If the user just visits `domain.com/abtus` and not `domain.com/abtus.php` the URL the user has visited doesn't show up. How can I fix this without rewrite rules. Potentially redirect and append the URL?

Comment: I tried it myself on a local server and `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` shows the URL no matter if it has an extension or not.

Comment: I've used PHP to hide all except the final destination. May this be a factor?

Comment: Well, if you use the script above, you keep referring to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, that one shows the path to the running script -> the error.php. You have to use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, which tells you the URL user requested.